# What is "db" in Prisma datasource block?

Tags: database, mongodb, orm, prisma, odm

In [Prisma For MongogDB](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/mongodb/connect-your-database-node-mongodb) quick start guide, they wrote something like the following

```
datasource db {
provider = "mongodb"
url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

My question is what is "**db**" right after "*datasource*" keyword?

Answer (score 1):

The value `db` is tied to the name of the `datasource` in your schema file.

datasource db is a convention - however, you can give your data source any name - for example, datasource mysql or datasource data.

Here's a reference for [datasource](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datasource) which should be helpful.

In your schema file when using [native database types](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#mongodb-preview) you need to refer to the datasource name which is defined. So if your datasource is defined as `data` you would refer the native type as `@data.String` instead of conventional `@db.String`